# Castle Windsor Setting log level when logging to console

Tags: logging, castle-windsor, windsor-facilities

I'm new to Castle Windsor and am struggling to setup the initial log level of ConsoleLogger. The documentation gives some hints for *log4net* but is silent about logging to console.

My code looks as follows:

```
container.AddFacility<Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility>(
    f => f.LogUsing(Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggerImplementation.Console));
```

Any hints how I can set the default log level of the facility to e.g. `LoggerLevel.Warn`?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is supported if you take direct dependency on `ILogger` rather than `ILoggerFactory`. Feel free to request this in the issue tracker.